# Delineate Excel Formula Without Using Wizards

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

Is there a combination of excel formulas that I could use to do this without using VBA or the import wizard?  I know how to insert comma delimited data from a text file and to split a cell into multiple columns one time, but I need to use formulas to do this so the data updates when changed without the user needing to repeat the process.

If people think I need VBA to do this I will repost the question on StackOverflow, but I would rather  just use built-in excel formulas here so it updates automatically.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your comma delimited data is in a single cell or column, you can certainly split it across columns by using worksheet functions. I'm not so sure you can reference an external (text) file and automatically change the Excel file when the text file is altered using only worksheet functions. Which of the two are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: If your data is saved as a CSV file, excel can handle this natively. If it's a text file, you have to use VBA for automatic imports. If it's a text file and you're OK with manual imports, you can do it with formulas in the next columns using a combination of `MID` and `FIND`.